# How to effectively manage different routes with conditional statements in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I've implemented a simple routing in my react app as follows:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const { profileId, isActive, setActiveProfile, disconnectProfile } = useProfileManager();

  let routes;

  if (isActive) {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/products" exact>
          <Products />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/profiles" exact>
          <Profiles />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/installation" exact>
          <Installation />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/" />
      </Switch>
    );
  } else {
    routes = (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/profiles" exact>
          <Profiles />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/profiles" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }

  return (
    <ProfileContext.Provider
      value={{
        profileId: profileId,
        isActive: isActive,
        setActiveProfile: setActiveProfile,
        disconnectProfile: disconnectProfile,
      }}
    >
      <Router>
        <main>
           {routes}
        </main>
      </Router>
    </ProfileContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

`isActive` is a boolean value returned by the `useProfileManager` and it's working as I expected.
When I start the app it redirects immediately to the `/profiles` path but I'm also able to access all the other paths if the `isActive` value is true. I want that it redirects to my Home page to the `/` path if `isActive` is `true` and not to the `/profiles` path.

How can I fix that?

Comment: what i would suggest is save isActive in global store and use withrouter and connect your app to your store and use isActive to redirect from you root component which is App

Comment: Can clean up all irrelevant parts? I feel that 90% of the code here is irrelevant to the actual problem

Comment: Ok, I simplified my question, hoping the code provided is enough...

Comment: @FDG In your description, when you access the other paths if the `isActive` value is true, do you access them by clicking a link or do you navigate to them by entering the desired url in the address bar of your browser?

Comment: Hi @Tejogol, I use a `NavLink` in my navigation bar. I think the problem is that the isActive is returned as a callback, so the first result is false and then true. If I `console.log(1)` after the if statement`and console.log(2)`  after the else it prints `2` `1`

Comment: @FDG Yes, I agree with your identification of the problem. My hypothesis was that it was a race condition, but I wanted to first confirm that you were navigating using a link instead of entering the desired url in the address bar because in the latter case it wouldn't be possible to reproduce your issue. I created a simplified codesandbox to illustrate the issue and will add it to the answers below.

Comment: I should just change the /profiles path in the else statement with another path name that is not in the if block, but it's just a trick... don't like it. Thanks for your help, much appreciated @Tejogol

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your are experiencing a race condition where `isActive` is initially `null` thereby initially sending you down the "inActive" route. When the `isActive` value is later updated to be `true` you are allowed to navigate the `isActive` routes.

You're able to navigate the `isActive` routes if you're navigating using a link instead of entering the desired url in the address bar.

I've put together a simplified CodeSandBox containing a delay to simulate the issue.

Debugging was a challenge because you used the same route for `<Profiles>` regardless of whether `isActive` is `true` or not, thereby masking the issue.

[image: Working Example]

Comment: Yes, it's exactly what I did for the moment, just changed the path name in my else statement that is not in my if block. Don't know if it's a good solution, maybe it's just a trick. At least we have focused the problem. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @FDG The route name change is not a solution, it just helps make the issue easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: I edited my question with some extra code that show how the isActive is returned @Tejogol

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to insert a conditional like that.

Create a component (ProtectedRoute, for example) to manage the redirect.

```
const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {

  // If you pass as props
  const {isActive} = {...rest};
  
  // If you receive from useProfileManager function
  const {isActive} = useProfileManager();

  return (<Route {...rest} render={() => isActive ? (<Redirect to={{pathName: '/'}} />) : (<Component />)})

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

After that, import and call the component in your routes.js.

```
<Switch>
  <ProtectedRoute path="/products" exact component={Products} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Victor but it doens't change the behaviour. Problem isn't unfortunately solved.

Comment: The useProfileManager function is asynchronous?

Comment: If you want read the code, I edited my question with the useProfileManager hook.Thanks